# Sonar Cloud Install for Static Analysis Fails

Tags: yaml, sonarqube

Carefully read over all similar questions, none of these match what I am running into.

This is likely a path config issue.  It's looking like 'too complex a problem' and that usually means there's a simple error :).

Below is the error I get from the workflow log, the updated code being used in my workflow and then the suggested Sonar Cloud YAML.

The local repo path is correct.  This repo is synced with GitHub, has been working all along. Thus the error 'can't find a part of the path' doesn't quite make sense.

**Error Info from the log:**

> Directory: D:\Clients**************Services\Azure%20Training\CICD%20Git%20Hub%20Actions\Repos\PSCIDemoRepo\PSCIDemo.sonar
>
> `Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name`
> `----                 -------------         ------ ----`
> `d-----         8/29/2023   4:50 PM                scanner`
> Tool 'dotnet-sonarscanner' failed to update due to the following:
> Failed to install tool package 'dotnet-sonarscanner': Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Clients*****************Services\Azure%20Training\CICD%20Git%20Hub%20Actions\Repos\PSCIDemoRepo\PSCIDemo.sonar\scanner.store.stage\ks1t1zcl.c3u\dotnet-sonarscanner'.
> Tool 'dotnet-sonarscanner' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> * You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
> * A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
> * The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> * You mistyped the name of the tool.
>
> For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
>
>
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

**Here is my YAML.**
**Used the code button but this didn't format.**

Tried typing in a valid version, this didn't resolve anything.

```yaml
- name: Install SonarCloud scanner
        if: steps.cache-sonar-scanner.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          New-Item -Path \Clients\*******Services\Azure%20Training\CICD%20Git%20Hub%20Actions\Repos\PSCIDemoRepo\PSCIDemo\.sonar\scanner -ItemType Directory
          dotnet tool update dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.5.3 --tool-path \Clients\*******Services\Azure%20Training\CICD%20Git%20Hub%20Actions\Repos\PSCIDemoRepo\PSCIDemo\.sonar\scanner
      - name: Build and analyze
```

**Here is the YAML code generated by Sonar Cloud.**
**Used the code button but this didn't format.**

The relative path wasn't working at all, so copied/pasted the fully qualified path.  At least then the install was attempted.

```yaml
- name: Install SonarCloud scanner
        if: steps.cache-sonar-scanner.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          New-Item -Path .\.sonar\scanner -ItemType Directory
          dotnet tool update dotnet-sonarscanner --tool-path .\.sonar\scanner
      - name: Build and analyze
```

Comment: Filburt, how'd you format this? :)

I tried '''code''' many times, what did I not see here?  Looks loads nicer than what I posted.

Many thanks.

Comment: I like to use blockquote `>` and ```\``` linebreaks to format error messages/output to distinguish from code. Just [edit] to see the source.